# Improve speed of video correction algorithm based on locked bitmap, getpixel and optimized auxiliary functions

Tags: c#, performance, getpixel, lockbits

I wrote this code to remove annoying patterns in a video due to camera malfunction. The problem is that to encode a 2 Minute video this algorithm needs more than **2 hours**. I want to significantly reduce the time needed.

The algorithm iterates over each image, looks at each 4 pixels from there, creates the average and if the average is below a threshold, sets the current pixel to white. I could use step = 2 and set the 2x2 matrix to white, yet this deteriorates images quality and only increases speed by half.

I already added the `lockbitmap`, `lockbits` and improved the auxiliary functions.

Before and after the `using (d2 = reader.ReadVideoFrame())`-snippet I have an aforge videoreader and writer based on ffmpeg.

```
using (d2 = reader.ReadVideoFrame())
{
    LockBitmap lockBitmap = new LockBitmap(d2);
    lockBitmap.LockBits();

    Color v = Color.FromArgb(240, 237, 241);
    for (int x = 0; x < lockBitmap.Width-1; x = x + 1)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < lockBitmap.Height-1; y = y + 1)
        {
            Color dus = durchschnitt(lockBitmap.GetPixel(x, y),
                lockBitmap.GetPixel(x + 1, y),
                lockBitmap.GetPixel(x, y + 1),
                lockBitmap.GetPixel(x + 1, y + 1));
            if (abstand(dus, v) < 50)
            {
                lockBitmap.SetPixel(x, y, Color.White);
            }
        }
    }
    lockBitmap.UnlockBits();
}
```

Auxiliary functions:

```
private Color durchschnitt(Color c1, Color c2, Color c3, Color c4)
{
    return Color.FromArgb((int)((c1.R + c2.R + c3.R + c4.R) / 4),
        (int)((c1.G + c2.G + c3.G + c4.G) / 4),
        (int)((c1.B + c2.B + c3.B + c4.B) / 4));
}
```

and

```
private double abstand(Color c1, Color c2)
{
    return Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(c2.R - c1.R, 2) + Math.Pow(c2.G - c1.G, 2) + Math.Pow(c2.B - c1.B, 2));
}
```

`LockBitmap` is from [here](https://www.codeproject.com/tips/240428/work-with-bitmap-faster-with-csharp).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not how `lockBits` work.

In short you need to lock the bits to get access to the scanline via pointers. Best to use 32bpp for integer access. You can calculate the pixel in the contiguous array as follows.

You will need to decorate you class or your method with the [`unsafe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/unsafe) keyword and also set the project build option to use unsafe code, you use pointers.

```
var w = bmp.Width;
var h = bmp.Height;

// lock the array for direct access
var data = bmp.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, w, h), ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, PixelFormat.Format32bppPArgb);
var scan0Ptr = (int*)data.Scan0;

// get the stride
var stride = data.Stride / 4;

// scan all x
for (var x = 0; x < w; x++)
{
   var pX = scan0Ptr + x;

   // scan all y
   for (var y = 0; y < h; y++)
   {
      // this is now your pixel *p, which essentially is a pointer to
      // to a memory which contains your pixel
      var p = pX + y * stride;

      // or for better access to X and Y
      var p = scan0Ptr + x + y * stride;

      // or alternatively you can just access you pixel with the following notation  
      *(scan0Ptr + x + y * stride) // <== just use this like any variable 

      // example how to convert pixel *p to a Color
      var color = Color.FromArgb(*p);

      // example Convert a Color back to *p and update the pixel
      *p = Color.White.ToArgb();
   }
}
// unlock the bitmap
bmp.UnlockBits(data);
```

I'll leave the rest of the details up to you, however this will give you the best performance (minus some micro optimizations).

Lastly reducing the calls to external methods will also give you a performance boost; however, if you really need to, you can help the CLR by using `MethodImplOptions` Enum for `AggressiveInlining`

**E.g**

```
[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
private Color durchschnitt(Color c1, Color c2, Color c3, Color c4)
```

Also you might get a performance boost, by shifting out the components:

```
var r = ((*p >> 16) & 255);
var g = ((*p >> 8) & 255);
var b = ((*p >> 0) & 255);
```

And you could probably multi-thread this workload.

Comment: By using your recommendations, I reached 1 hour for 2:10 1920 x 1080 Video at 52.26fps. Yes, `unsafe` is necessary.

Comment: @FabienBiller the next step would be get this happening on multiple cores

Comment: I do have 8 and cuda. Do you have ideas?

Comment: Maybe best to ask another question, but yeah definitely threaded or gpu would probably eat this

Comment: @FabienBiller Also id start micro optimizing it, you could knock a lot off by making sure every line of code is efficient in the loop, ie there is a lot of conversions to and from color ect

Comment: now I am at 49 minutes having removed all `FromArgb`.

Comment: @FabienBiller now i think you can smash it in half or more with multiple threads, or even more on the cuda

Comment: With Parallel.Foreach I brought it down to 12 minutes. Let's see, what CUDA can do. BTW: How many elements, I use a List<Bitmap>, should be in it at once? I am currently using 30. It makes my CPU peak, memory is fine though.

Comment: @FabienBiller The MaxDegreeOfParallelism property affects the number of concurrent operations run by Parallel method calls that are passed this ParallelOptions instance. A positive property value limits the number of concurrent operations to the set value. If it is -1, there is no limit on the number of concurrently running operations.

Comment: By default, For and ForEach will utilize however many threads the underlying scheduler provides, so changing MaxDegreeOfParallelism from the default only limits how many concurrent tasks will be used.

Comment: @FabienBiller So dont limit what goes into the for loop unless you have memory problems, and dont set the MaxDegreeOfParallelism, however experiment and see what works best for you